# Mutli-Line Writing To File In If Statement Batch

Tags: file, batch-file, if-statement, cmd

So I'm making something in batch and for some reason it says this code is wrong.
I think it has to do with the file writing inside the if statement but I don't know, any ideas?

```
if %firsttime% == 1 (

:firsttime

cls

echo Loading...
echo Performing first time setup.

(
echo 0
echo %language%
) > programinfo.txt

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your snippet is not complete but from what I see I have two assumptions - you are setting a value inside brackets.If so you'll need [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and referring your variables enclosed with `!` instead with `%` . Seeing the label  there's a chance you are using goto inside brackets - [which breaks their context](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)

Comment: Well I tried !language! and fixed the goto, but the code still says, "Set wasn't expected at this time."

Comment: @Woowing - paste your whole code. It's hard to guess like that.

Comment: @Woowing - This is the first time you actually show the error message! strike one. And the error message tells you there is something wrong with a SET statement, yet you don't even show code with that statement in it. strike two. You are not providing nearly enough information for anyone to help you.

Comment: Welp, I fixed it!